# Solr Nested Documents - Schema

Tags: solr, information-retrieval

I’m using SolrCloud version 8.4. I’m having trouble getting nested document
indexing and querying work. Can anyone give a basic schema for the example data
in Solr documentation:

```
[{ "id": "P11!prod",
   "name_s": "Swingline Stapler",
   "description_t": "The Cadillac of office staplers ...",
   "skus": [ { "id": "P11!S21",
               "color_s": "RED",
               "price_i": 42,
               "manuals": [ { "id": "P11!D41",
                              "name_s": "Red Swingline Brochure",
                              "pages_i":1,
                              "content_t": "..."
                            } ]
             },
             { "id": "P11!S31",
               "color_s": "BLACK",
               "price_i": 3
             } ],
   "manuals": [ { "id": "P11!D51",
                  "name_s": "Quick Reference Guide",
                  "pages_i":1,
                  "content_t": "How to use your stapler ..."
                },
                { "id": "P11!D61",
                  "name_s": "Warranty Details",
                  "pages_i":42,
                  "content_t": "... lifetime guarantee ..."
                } ]
 },
 { "id": "P22!prod",
   "name_s": "Mont Blanc Fountain Pen",
   "description_t": "A Premium Writing Instrument ...",
   "skus": [ { "id": "P22!S22",
               "color_s": "RED",
               "price_i": 89,
               "manuals": [ { "id": "P22!D42",
                              "name_s": "Red Mont Blanc Brochure",
                              "pages_i":1,
                              "content_t": "..."
                            } ]
             },
             { "id": "P22!S32",
               "color_s": "BLACK",
               "price_i": 67
             } ],
   "manuals": [ { "id": "P22!D52",
                  "name_s": "How To Use A Pen",
                  "pages_i":42,
                  "content_t": "Start by removing the cap ..."
                } ]
 } ]
```

All examples on the internet are talking about how to index such a document but
none of them give a sample schema file like it’s a closely guarded mystery.

Does anyone know how to set up a schema file for this data? Preferably in JSON rather than XML, but both are fine

Comment: Here is an example of an schema.xml file that defines fields: https://github.com/pulibrary/pul_solr/blob/main/solr_configs/pdc-discovery/conf/schema.xml -- these files then to be very specific to the application

Comment: You can create this schema.xml file directly on your server or use the Schema API to do it: https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/main/tutorial.md#customizing-our-schema

Comment: As per my experience, Solr Work on flat schema (mostly). So it better to flatten your data